# powershell get-counter for msmq queue performance counter not working

Tags: powershell, msmq

I want to get message size/count in MSMQ queue using performance counters
like $messageSize= get-counter -counter ""....
Could you please some one give complete syntax for this

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you've come up with along with any error messages.  This is not a code requesting site.

Comment: 1- find counterset for msmq, 2 get the counter. `$set=Get-Counter -ListSet * |?{ $_.countersetname -match "msmq"} ; $set |%{Get-Counter $_.counter}`

Answer (score 2):

```
gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue | ft -property Name, MessagesInQueue
```